# Generic registration with Autofac?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I can manually register my repositories like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Account>>().As<IRepositoryAsync<Account>>();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<User>>().As<IRepositoryAsync<User>>();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Order>>().As<IRepositoryAsync<Order>>();
```

But can't seem to register them automatically. I've tried a few things with no luck, namely this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Account).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>)))
    .AsSelf()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

..and this

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Account).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resolve a `IRepositoryAsync<Foo>`, try this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>));

IContainer container = builder.Build();

IRepository<Foo> fooRepository = container.Resolve<IRepositoryAsync<Foo>>();
```

Both of your two solutions are similar and will work if you have a `FooRepository`.

For example :

```
public class FooRepository : IRepositoryAsync<Foo> 
{ }

// ...

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(FooRepository).Assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>));
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Repository<>)).As(typeof (IRepositoryAsync<>));